# Cannot resolve symbol setMinValue

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use a NumberPicker in Android Studio. Yet when I try to use setMinValue(), it gives me an error saying "Cannot resolve symbol setMinValue." According to (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html), setMinValue() is a valid function for NumberPicker. I have tried Build -> Clean Project and that did not work either. Please help me!

My code is:

`NumberPicker picker = (NumberPicker) findViewByID (R.id.LanguagePicker);
String[] things = new String[] ("this", "that");
picker.setMinValue(0);`

Comment: I've fixed the problem (the problem was I had setContentView() that was linking to the wrong XML file.)

Answer (score 0):

It should work.

I used this way once to make time picker

```
NumberPicker myTimeHour = (NumberPicker) myView.findViewById(R.id.time_hour);
NumberPicker myTimeMinutes = (NumberPicker) myView.findViewById(R.id.time_minutes);
myTimeMinutes.setMinValue(0);
myTimeMinutes.setMaxValue(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.minutes_item).length - 1);
myTimeMinutes.setDisplayedValues(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.minutes_item));
myTimeHour.setMinValue(0);
myTimeHour.setMaxValue(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hour_item).length - 1);
myTimeHour.setDisplayedValues(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hour_item));
```

For your situation, the code should be the following

```
NumberPicker picker = (NumberPicker) myView.findViewById(R.id.LanguagePicker);
myTimeMinutes.setMinValue(0);
myTimeMinutes.setMaxValue(1);
myTimeMinutes.setDisplayedValues(new String[]{"this", "that"});
```

The documentation show the following about max value:
*The length of the displayed values array set via setDisplayedValues(String[]) must be equal to the range of selectable numbers which is equal to getMaxValue() - getMinValue() + 1.*

Please attach entire code and stack trace errors

Comment: I am trying to use the NumberPicker as an item where you can select things, not to display the time.

Comment: You have to use the same approach.

Comment: The value can get from an array by getResource().getStringArray(R.array.ArrayName). 
Please

Comment: Update your post with full code and stack trace with errors